# How to update the state in pinia with Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, store, pinia

I'm trying to save the input values in the Pinia store, but the state is not updating. So I want `onSubmit` function to save the input values in a store.

My code :
**Create.vue**

```html
<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue";
import { useCounterStore } from '@/stores/counter';
const counter = useCounterStore();

const form = reactive({
    first: "",
    second: "",
    email: ""
});

const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    counter.$patch({ firstName: form.first.value });
    counter.$patch({ secondName: form.second.value });
    counter.$patch({ email: form.email.value });
}
</script>

<template>
<form @submit="onSubmit">
        {{ counter.getFirst + 'MYFIRST' }} {{ counter.getSecond + 'MYSECOND' }} {{ counter.getEmail + 'MYEMAIL' }}
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">First</label>
                <input v-model="form.first" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                    placeholder="First name">
            </div>        <div class="col-6">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Second</label>
                <input v-model="form.second" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                    placeholder="Second name">
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 mt-2">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email</label>
                <input v-model="form.email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                    placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                <button @click="onSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-dark push-       right">Create</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">All users</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

Pinia store: **counter.js**

```js
   import { ref, computed, reactive } from 'vue'
   import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

   export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', () => {
    const count = ref(0);

    let firstName = ref('');
    let secondName = ref('');
    let email = ref('');

    const getFirst = computed(() => firstName.value)
    const getSecond = computed(() => secondName.value)
    const getEmail = computed(() => email.value)

    function increment() {
      count.value++
    }

    return { count, getFirst, getSecond, getEmail, increment }
   })
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're in the process of learning Vue, don't give up!
Give a feedback in comment and put your post on "solved" status if this help you.

The solution :

In **store file** :

```html
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', {
  state: () => ({
    loginForm: {
      firstName: '',
      secondName: '',
      email: ''
    }
  })
});
```

In **Create.vue** :

```html
<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue";
import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/auth';
const authstore = useAuthStore();

const form = reactive({
    first: "",
    second: "",
    email: ""
});

...

const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    authStore.loginForm.firstName = form.first;
    authStore.loginForm.secondName = form.second;
    authStore.loginForm.email = form.email;
}

...

<script/>
```

Comment: nicest person in the stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure how your store look like... but it should by something like:
`

```
 import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

    export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
    state: () => {
    return { count: 0 }
    }
   })`
```

in your component, change the name of the store instance, lets say counterStore.

```
const counterStore = useCounterStore();
```

and now you can access the state by name:

```
counterStore.counter++
```

while this will work, it is not the best practice...
you should use actions to manipulate the state...

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
  state: () => {
    return { count: 0 }
  },
  actions: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    },
  },
})
```

and then you can call the action like a regular method:

```
counterStore.increment()
```